# JQuery How can I add a class to this?

Tags: jquery, class

I need to add a class to this span in this line of code:

```
$(":text").after("<span>*</span>")
```

How do I add a class to this?

I have tried

```
$(":text").after("<span>*</span>").addClass("error");
```

and

```
$(":text").after('<span class="error">*</span>');
```

Comment: It needs to specifically be THIS line of code with a class, not anything like this: `$('<span />', {
        "class": 'test',
        text: "*",
        click: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test")
        }})`

Answer (score 1):

The `<span>` should have a class?

How about

```
$(":text").after('<span class="myclass">*</span>');
```

note the switch to single quotes...

Comment: Yes, the span should have a class. And I thought of that, but it doesn't add the class at all. It keeps the text plain.